# mysqli: Cannot create MANY to MANY table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have setup 3 Tables. One is for Ingredients. The other is for Meals and the last one is for the junction reference between the two. However every time I try to set a foreign key for "meal_fk", I get no defined index error, even though as far as I can tell, it IS indexed, or I set its attribute to indexed. So what am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: MEALS TABLE

[image]

INGREDIENTS

```
Table   Create Table    
ingredients     CREATE TABLE `ingredients` (
 `ingredient_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `quanity` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `package` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `item` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `cost` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `store` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reg_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ingredient_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

MEALS

```
Table   Create Table    
meals   CREATE TABLE `meals` (
 `meal_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ingredients` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `meal` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `cost` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reg_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`meal_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

JUNCTION INGREDIENTS MEALS

```
Table   Create Table    
junction_ingredients_meals  CREATE TABLE `junction_ingredients_meals` (
 `junction_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `ingredient_fk` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `meal_fk` int(6) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`junction_id`),
 KEY `ingredient_fk` (`ingredient_fk`,`meal_fk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: So, I don't see an image for the MEALS table...where it's saying an index doesn't exist (I'm looking for the PK of the meals table) as the screenshot you gave for grocery doesn't show the tables' PK or indexes that I can see...

Comment: Instead of images, show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` as plain text.

Comment: I added in the Meals Table. Barmar: sorry i'm new to learning mysqli with php. This is day 2 for me. I don't understand what you mean by show create table tablename.

Comment: He means run the following queries: `SHOW CREATE TABLE MEALS`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE INGREDIENTS`, etc... and post those results rather than images.

Comment: Okay, I found where to do that and added it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see, referencing fields need to be exact same type as fields referenced (except they may be nullable even if the field referenced is not). Your issue is your referenced fields are `unsigned int`, and your referencing ones are `int`.